# Why does this function push RAX to the stack as the first operation?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, x86-64, abi

In the assembly of the C++ source below.  Why is RAX pushed to the stack?

RAX, as I understand it from the ABI could contain anything from the calling function. But we save it here, and then later move the stack back by 8 bytes.  So the RAX on the stack is, I think only relevant for the `std::__throw_bad_function_call()` operation ... ?

The code:-

```
#include <functional> 

void f(std::function<void()> a) 
{
  a(); 
}
```

Output, from `gcc.godbolt.org`, using Clang 3.7.1 -O3:

```
f(std::function<void ()>):                  # @f(std::function<void ()>)
        push    rax
        cmp     qword ptr [rdi + 16], 0
        je      .LBB0_1
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     qword ptr [rdi + 24]    # TAILCALL
.LBB0_1:
        call    std::__throw_bad_function_call()
```

I'm sure the reason is obvious, but I'm struggling to figure it out.

Here's a tailcall without the `std::function<void()>` wrapper for comparison:

```
void g(void(*a)())
{
  a(); 
}
```

The trivial:

```
g(void (*)()):             # @g(void (*)())
        jmp     rdi        # TAILCALL
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [64-bit ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation.html) requires that the stack is aligned to 16 bytes before a `call` instruction.

`call` pushes an 8-byte return address on the stack, which breaks the alignment, so the compiler needs to do something to align the stack again to a multiple of 16 before the next `call`.

(The ABI design choice of requiring alignment before a `call` instead of after has the minor advantage that if any args were passed on the stack, this choice makes the first arg 16B-aligned.)

Pushing a don't-care value works well, and can be *more* efficient than `sub rsp, 8` on [CPUs with a stack engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631576/what-is-the-stack-engine-in-the-sandybridge-microarchitecture).  (See the comments).

Comment: Ah - I was thinking about it wrong and not really believing that fact that RAX was a garbage value  :)   Mystery solved!

Comment: Actually it's the other way around. Before the call the stack must be aligned, so after the call it is unaligned and must be realigned.

Comment: I have to concur with @Dani . When transfer is controlled via the call to function `f`, RSP is already misaligned by 8 because the return address was placed on the stack. It was aligned to a 16-byte boundary just before control was transferred to `f`. Possibly you meant that after `push rax` the stack is once again aligned to a 16-byte boundary. The code actually adds 8 back to _RSP_ when the branch isn't taken just before the _JMP_. It is inefficient code to get this job done.

Comment: I wonder why not use sub rsp, 8 so there's no unnecessary memory write.

Comment: @Gene I could see it if it was being optimized for space over speed.

Comment: @Gene: `sub rsp, 8` requires an extra uop for the stack-engine to sync its offset value of rsp with the value in the out-of-order core.  So on modern Intel CPUs (but not AMD), it's actually more efficient to do one `push` of garbage than to manually modify `rsp` by just 8.  (The stack engine is what makes it possible for `push` / `pop` to be single-uop instructions, instead of needing an extra uop to modify `rsp`).  See [Agner Fog's microarch.pdf](http://agner.org/optimize/) for the details.  The stack engine was new in Pentium-M, but AMD has it too thanks to their patent-sharing agreement.

Comment: ...continued for Gene and @MichaelPetch: the memory write will almost always hit in cache, so that's not really a concern other than store-port bandwidth.  IIRC, clang uses this trick but gcc doesn't (not even with `-mtune=haswell` or something.)

Comment: @PeterCordes : On GCC is seems to change between versions. GCC 5.3 (and some early versions) seem to use `push rax` in the generated code (for this case) and then in 6.1 it uses `sub`. I still don't quite understand why CLANG just doesn't do the stack alignment before the `call std::__throw_bad_function_call()` rather than doing a push/pop in the path more likely to be executed.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: oh that's funky.  Only in this `std::function` case, though, [not in simple cases like `return foo() + 1;`](https://godbolt.org/g/kTylNj).  And `-mtune=intel` makes it use `LEA` to modify rsp.  Maybe that comes from tuning for Atom, which is an Intel CPU.  (and gcc's tuning for atom uses LEA for everything possible; IDK if that's actually good).

Comment: Peter don't you think you should have let the OP update his own question? Basically there is nothing left of his answer. Might have been better to produce a new answer? It isn't like this OP has gone AWOL. Only been 12 hours since he answered. I would have waited to see if they would have updated it themselves (giving some time) based on comments.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: you mean this answer?  Yeah, I guess it's only been 12 hours since Dani's comment pointing out the error.  BeniBela: feel free to roll back and write it in your own words.  I can post the extra commentary I added about efficiency and ABI-design as a separate answer if you want.  I made the edit since the answer was fundamentally correct already, but just got the details wrong.  I got impatient :P

Answer (score 13):

The reason `push rax` is there is to align the stack back to a 16-byte boundary to conform to the [64-bit System V ABI](http://web.archive.org/web/20160604152439/http://www.x86-64.org/documentation.html) in the case where `je .LBB0_1` branch is taken. The value placed on the stack isn't relevant. Another way would have been subtracting 8 from *RSP* with `sub rsp, 8`. The ABI states the alignment this way:

> The end of the input argument area shall be aligned on a 16 (32, if __m256 is
>   passed on stack) byte boundary. In other words, the value (%rsp + 8) is always
>   a multiple of 16 (32) when control is transferred to the function entry point. The stack pointer, %rsp, always points to the end of the latest allocated stack frame.

Prior to the call to function `f` the stack was 16-byte aligned per the calling convention. After control was transferred via a *CALL* to `f` the return address was placed on the stack misaligning the stack by 8. `push rax` is a simple way of subtracting 8 from *RSP* and realigning it again. If the branch is taken to `call std::__throw_bad_function_call()`the stack will be properly aligned for that call to work.

In the case where the comparison falls through, the stack will appear just as it did at function entry once the `add rsp, 8` instruction is executed. The return address of the *CALLER* to function `f` will now be back at the top of the stack and the stack will be misaligned by 8 again. This is what we want because a [TAIL CALL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) is being made with `jmp qword ptr [rdi + 24]` to transfer control to the function `a`. This will *JMP* to the function not *CALL* it. When function `a` does a *RET* it will return directly back to the function that called `f`.

At a higher optimization level I would have expected that the compiler should be smart enough to do the comparison, and let it fall through directly to the *JMP*. What is at label `.LBB0_1` could then align the stack to a 16-byte boundary so that `call std::__throw_bad_function_call()` works properly.

---

As @CodyGray pointed out, if you use *GCC* (not *CLANG*) with optimization level of `-O2` or higher, the code produced does seem more reasonable. *GCC* 6.1 output from [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'+-fverbose-asm+-O3+',source:'%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E+%0A%0Avoid+f(std::function%3Cvoid()%3E+a)+%0A%7B%0A++a()%3B+%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) is:

```
f(std::function<void ()>):
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rdi+16], 0     # MEM[(bool (*<T5fc5>) (union _Any_data &, const union _Any_data &, _Manager_operation) *)a_2(D) + 16B],
        je      .L7 #,
        jmp     [QWORD PTR [rdi+24]]      # MEM[(const struct function *)a_2(D)]._M_invoker
.L7:
        sub     rsp, 8    #,
        call    std::__throw_bad_function_call()        #
```

This code is more in line with what I would have expected. In this case it would appear that *GCC*'s optimizer may handle this code generation better than *CLANG*.

Comment: Indeed, what you describe in the last paragraph is [exactly what GCC does](https://godbolt.org/g/NXuw0F) at either -O2 or -O3. Clang and ICC both align the stack at the top of the function. This is one of those rare cases where GCC's optimizer seems to be more effective than Clang's.

Comment: @CodyGray now that I have had coffee, I did toss it on Godbolt and you are correct _GCC_ looks to generate better code in this situation. I amended my answer to reflect that finding. That also confirmed my comment about how I would have expected it to be optimized.

Comment: @daniel: your other edit to an answer to this question has been declined as you are changing the answer drastically with the edit. If you have your own answer to provide, then please feel free to do so, but you should avoid such drastic changes unless the answer is a community wiki type answer.

Answer (score 7):

In other cases, clang typically fixes up the stack before returning [with a `pop rcx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775975/clang-useless-push-rax-and-pop-rcx).

Using `push` has an upside for efficiency in code-size (`push` is only 1 byte vs. 4 bytes for `sub rsp, 8`), and also in uops on Intel CPUs.  (No need for a stack-sync uop, which you'd get if you access `rsp` directly because the `call` that brought us to the top of the current function makes the stack engine "dirty").

**This long and rambling answer discusses the worst-case performance risks of using `push rax` / `pop rcx` for aligning the stack, and whether or not `rax` and `rcx` are good choices of register.**  (Sorry for making this so long.)

(TL:DR: looks good, the possible downside is usually small and the upside in the common case makes this worth it.  Partial-register stalls could be a problem on Core2/Nehalem if `al` or `ax` are "dirty", though.  No other 64-bit capable CPU has big problems (because they don't rename partial regs, or merge efficiently), and 32-bit code needs more than 1 extra `push` to align the stack by 16 for another `call` unless it was already saving/restoring some call-preserved regs for its own use.)

---

**Using `push rax` instead of `sub rsp, 8` introduces a dependency on the old value of `rax`**, so you'd think it might slow things down if the value of `rax` is the result of a long-latency dependency chain (and/or a cache miss).

e.g. the caller might have done something slow with `rax` that's unrelated to the function args, like `var = table[ x % y ];  var2 = foo(x);`

```
# example caller that leaves RAX not-ready for a long time

mov   rdi, rax              ; prepare function arg

div   rbx                   ; very high latency
mov   rax, [table + rdx]    ; rax = table[ value % something ], may miss in cache
mov   [rsp + 24], rax       ; spill the result.

call  foo                   ; foo uses push rax to align the stack
```

Fortunately out-of-order execution will do a good job here.

The `push` doesn't make the value of `rsp` dependent on `rax`.  (It's either handled by the stack engine, or on very old CPUs `push` decodes to multiple uops, one of which updates `rsp` independently of the uops that store `rax`.  Micro-fusion of the store-address and store-data uops let `push` be a single fused-domain uop, even though stores always take 2 unfused-domain uops.)

As long as nothing depends on the output `push rax` / `pop rcx`, it's not a problem for out-of-order execution.  If `push rax` has to wait because `rax` isn't ready, it won't *cause* the ROB (ReOrder Buffer) to fill up and eventually block the execution of later independent instruction.  The ROB would fill up even without the `push` because the instruction that's slow to produce `rax`, and whatever instruction in the caller consumes `rax` before the call are even older, and can't retire either until `rax` is ready.  Retirement has to happen in-order in case of exceptions / interrupts.

(I don't think a cache-miss load can retire before the load completes, leaving just a load-buffer entry.  But even if it could, it wouldn't make sense to produce a result in a call-clobbered register without reading it with another instruction before making a `call`.  **The caller's instruction that consumes `rax` definitely can't execute/retire until our `push` can do the same.**)

When `rax` does become ready, `push` can execute and retire in a couple cycles, allowing later instructions (which were already executed out of order) to also retire.  The store-address uop will have already executed, and I assume the store-data uop can complete in a cycle or two after being dispatched to the store port.  Stores can retire as soon as the data is written to the store buffer.  Commit to L1D happens after retirement, when the store is known to be non-speculative.

So even in the worst case, where the instruction that produces `rax` was so slow that it led to the ROB filling up with independent instructions that are mostly already executed and ready to retire, having to execute `push rax` only causes a couple extra cycles of delay before independent instructions after it can retire.  (And some of the caller's instructions will retire first, making a bit of room in the ROB even before our `push` retires.)

---

**A `push rax` that has to wait will tie up some other microarchitectural resources**, leaving one fewer entry for finding parallelism between other later instructions.  (An `add rsp,8` that could execute would only be consuming a ROB entry, and not much else.)

It will use up one entry in the out-of-order scheduler (aka Reservation Station / RS).  The store-address uop can execute as soon as there's a free cycle, so only the store-data uop will be left.  The `pop rcx` uop's load address is ready, so it should dispatch to a load port and execute.  (When the `pop` load executes, it finds that its address matches the incomplete `push` store in the store buffer (aka memory order buffer), so it sets up the store-forwarding which will happen after the store-data uop executes.  This probably consumes a load buffer entry.)

Even an old CPUs like [Nehalem has a 36 entry RS, vs. 54 in Sandybridge](http://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/5/), or 97 in Skylake.  Keeping 1 entry occupied for longer than usual in rare cases is nothing to worry about.  The alternative of executing two uops (stack-sync + `sub`) is worse.

(**off topic**)
The ROB is larger than the RS, 128 (Nehalem), 168 (Sandybridge), 224 (Skylake).  (It holds fused-domain uops from issue to retirement, vs. the RS holding unfused-domain uops from issue to execution).  At 4 uops per clock max frontend throughput, that's over 50 cycles of delay-hiding on Skylake.  (Older uarches are less likely to sustain 4 uops per clock for as long...)

ROB size determines the out-of-order window for hiding a slow independent operation.  ([Unless register-file size limits are a smaller limit](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/)).  RS size determines the out-of-order window for finding parallelism between two separate dependency chains.  (e.g. consider a 200 uop loop body where every iteration is independent, but within each iteration it's one long dependency chain without much instruction-level parallelism (e.g. `a[i] = complex_function(b[i])`).  Skylake's ROB can hold more than 1 iteration, but we can't get uops from the next iteration into the RS until we're within 97 uops of the end of the current one.  If the dep chain wasn't so much larger than RS size, uops from 2 iterations could be in flight most of the time.)

---

**There are cases where `push rax / pop rcx` can be more dangerous**:

The caller of this function knows that `rcx` is call-clobbered, so won't read the value.  But it might have a false dependency on `rcx` after we return, like `bsf rcx, rax` / `jnz` or `test eax,eax` / `setz cl`.  [Recent Intel CPUs don't rename low8 partial registers anymore, so `setcc cl` has a false dep on `rcx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to).   `bsf` actually leaves its destination unmodified if the source is 0, even though Intel documents it as an undefined value.  AMD documents leave-unmodified behaviour.

The false dependency could create a loop-carried dep chain.  On the other hand, a false dependency can do that anyway, if our function wrote `rcx` with instructions dependent on its inputs.

It would be worse to use `push rbx`/`pop rbx` to save/restore a call-preserved register that we weren't going to use.  The caller likely *would* read it after we return, and we'd have introduced a store-forwarding latency into the caller's dependency chain for that register.  (Also, it's maybe more likely that `rbx` would be written right before the `call`, since anything the caller wanted to keep across the call would be moved to call-preserved registers like `rbx` and `rbp`.)

---

**On CPUs with partial-register stalls (Intel pre-Sandybridge)**, reading `rax` with `push` could cause a stall or 2-3 cycles on Core2 / Nehalem if the caller had done something like `setcc al` before the `call`.  Sandybridge doesn't stall while inserting a merging uop, and [Haswell and later don't rename low8 registers separately from `rax` at all.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to)

It would be nice to `push` a register that was less likely to have had its low8 used.  If compilers tried to avoid REX prefixes for code-size reasons, they'd avoid `dil` and `sil`, so `rdi` and `rsi` would be less likely to have partial-register issues.  But unfortunately gcc and clang don't seem to favour using `dl` or `cl` as 8-bit scratch registers, using `dil` or `sil` even in tiny functions where nothing else is using `rdx` or `rcx`.  (Although lack of low8 renaming in some CPUs means that `setcc cl` has a false dependency on the old `rcx`, so `setcc dil` is safer if the flag-setting was dependent on the function arg in `rdi`.)

`pop rcx` at the end "cleans" `rcx` of any partial-register stuff.  Since `cl` is used for shift counts, and functions do sometimes write just `cl` even when they could have written `ecx` instead.  (IIRC I've seen clang do this.  gcc more strongly favours 32-bit and 64-bit operand sizes to avoid partial-register issues.)

---

`push rdi` would probably be a good choice in a lot of cases, since the rest of the function also reads `rdi`, so introducing another instruction dependent on it wouldn't hurt.  It does stop out-of-order execution from getting the `push` out of the way if `rax` is ready before `rdi`, though.

---

Another potential downside is using cycles on the load/store ports.  But they are unlikely to be saturated, and the alternative is uops for the ALU ports.  With the extra stack-sync uop on Intel CPUs that you'd get from `sub rsp, 8`, that would be 2 ALU uops at the top of the function.