# In x86-64 do we always do pushq when we want to push something on the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention, att

Because all 16 registers can be 8 bytes in x86-64, at the beginning of a function call when the function (callee) has to push the callee saved  registers (%rbx, %rbp and %r12-15) it wants to use, it has no way of knowing whether the caller stored 64-bit or 32-bit or 16-bit or 8-bit values in those registers, so do they always have to call `pushq` to push the entire 8 bytes of those registers onto the stack, rather than `pushl`? In other words, are `pushl` and `pushw` ever used in x86-64?

Comment: There is no `pushl` on x86_64 and `pushw` is almost never used as it indeed pushes only 2 bytes, thus causing the stack to be out of alignment.

Comment: I know that "push dword" doesn't work in x64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The entire register is call-preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024672/what-registers-are-preserved-through-a-linux-x86-64-function-call), not just the low dword or word.  **Normal functions always save/restore the whole qword register** because that's the only safe thing to do, and it's also efficient enough that there's no reason to create a mechanism for functions to know when they could do anything else.

It's always efficient to read a full register after the 32-bit low half was written because [32-bit register writes implicitly zero-extend to 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6).  Reading a 64-bit register after the caller wrote the low 8 or 16-bits could cause a partial-register stall on Intel P6-family microarchitectures, if the caller was careless about how it used the register before making a `call`.  On modern uarches (not Intel P6), the 8/16-bit operand size register write already paid [whatever merging penalty might have existed (typically a false dependency)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers).  (I'm glossing over a couple details like partial AH renaming still being a thing on modern Intel, including Skylake)

---

While you *could* move the stack pointer with `sub $24, %rsp` and use `movl` or `movb` to store the 32-bit or 8-bit low parts of some registers, that's only safe if you know something about how your caller uses registers and want to optimize accordingly.  (Making your function dependent on the caller's internals, not just the ABI).  Even if that was an option for some helper function, it normally wouldn't be worth it to reduce the footprint of your stack frame by a few bytes.

(It's rare for functions to be using 16-bit data, but 8-bit data is not rare.  `bool` and `char` are common.  Compilers usually use `movzx` aka `movzbl` loads from memory to zero-extend to full registers, and can often use 32-bit operand size to avoid actually dealing with partial register shenanigans.  But they wouldn't care if you saved/restored only the low 8 bits with a mov store / movzbl reload, for registers where a compile is keeping a zero-extended bool or char.)

> Are `pushl` and pushw ever used in x86-64?

**`pushl` literally doesn't exist in 64-bit mode**; 32-bit operand-size for `push` is [not encodeable even with a `REX.W=0` prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127993/how-many-bytes-does-the-push-instruction-push-onto-the-stack-when-i-dont-specif).

`pushw` encodeable but never used by compilers in 32 or 64-bit mode.  (And generally not useful or recommended for humans, except for weird corner cases or hacks like maybe shellcode.  I did use it once when code-golfing (optimizing for code size) merging [two 16-bit values into one register for adler-32](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78972/30206)).

If a compiler did want to do word or dword stores, (e.g. in unoptimized builds to spill incoming register args), it would just use `movw` or `movl`.

**You generally want to keep the stack aligned by 16** so you're ready to make another function call; that's why I suggested `sub $24, %rsp` above.  (On function entry, RSP points at the return address your caller pushed.  RSP+8 and RSP-8 are 16-byte aligned.)

---

`pushq %reg` is very efficient on modern CPUs: decodes to a single uop on CPUs with [a stack engine (that handles the RSP updates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631576/what-is-the-stack-engine-in-the-sandybridge-microarchitecture) outside the OoO exec back-end.  It's so efficient that [clang uses `push %rax` or other dummy register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773787/why-does-this-function-push-rax-to-the-stack-as-the-first-operation) instead of `sub $8, %rsp` when it only needs to move the stack pointer by 8 bytes, e.g. to realign the stack before another call.

`pushq %reg` is a 1 byte instruction (or 2 bytes for r8..r15 including a REX prefix)

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer!