# Push/pop around a call on x86_64 (SysV ABI)

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

For

```
int callee(void);
int caller(void) { return callee()+1; }
```

gcc and clang generate (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/R6ZKZA):

clang:

```
caller:                                 # @caller
        push    rax
        call    callee
        inc     eax
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

gcc:

```
caller:                                 # @caller
        push    rax
        call    callee
        inc     eax
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

Why are the push/pop instructions around the call needed?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773787/why-does-this-function-push-rax-to-the-stack-as-the-first-operation) related?

Comment: @TonyTannous Yes. It answers the question.  Thanks! I'll close this this as a duplicate rather than delete it in case my phrasing helps others find the answer quicker.

Comment: Fun fact: clang does this at `-O3` as well as the `-Os` you used, because it's actually faster as well as more compact on some modern CPUs.  GCC still favours `sub`/`add` outside of `-Os`.