# What to do with an empty pop?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, callstack

I have the following function that stores a number on the stack (and modifies that number) and then at the end it cleans things up:

```
.rodata
number: .long   127     # need to keep original value

_start:

    # set up stack, align on 16 for syscalls
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    push number

    ...

  exit:
    pop ???
    mov %rbp, %rsp
    pop %rbp
    mov $SYS_EXIT,      %eax
    syscall
```

What should I be doing with the `pop` to get rid of the number (i.e., re-align the stack before exiting) ?

Comment: You can call "SYS_EXIT" without cleaning up the stack, which means that you can delete the "pop ???" and the 2 instructions after it and it won't matter.

Comment: `push number` loads 8 bytes from the absolute address `number`, but you only allocated 4 bytes of static data with `.long`.  Did you maybe mean `push $number` to push the address as an immediate, instead of loading from it?  Because if you did want to load, `push number(%rip)` is the more efficient way to address static storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use `add $8, %rsp` or simply pop into a register whose value you don't care about, like `pop %rcx`.

The latter is slightly preferable on recent systems due to the shorter code size and quirks of the "[stack engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631576/what-is-the-stack-engine-in-the-sandybridge-microarchitecture)" (explicit use of RSP can make Intel CPUs insert as stack-sync uop), but the former is not too bad either.

Some compilers (especially clang) do use dummy push/pop by default when they need to move RSP by exactly 8: [Why does this function push RAX to the stack as the first operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773787/why-does-this-function-push-rax-to-the-stack-as-the-first-operation)

---

Also note that your `pop` is redundant with `mov %rbp, %rsp` since you're using RBP as a frame pointer anyway.  And that an `_exit` system call doesn't care where RSP is pointing.